# matching multiple regular expressions using join

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a dictionary who's keys are all precompiled regular expressions. I want to match a string to any of these regular expressions.

When researching I found that you can match multiple regular expressions by joining them with the join method. But when I do so, I get a Type error:

```
import re

regex1 = re.compile("regex1.*")
regex2 = re.compile("regex2\d")
re_dict = {regex1 : "stuff", regex2 : "otherstuff"}
match_multiple = "|".join(list(re_dict.keys()))
string = 'regex25'
if re.match(match_multiple, string):
    print("matched")
```

This gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./a.py", line 7, in <module>
    match_multiple = "|".join(list(re_dict.keys()))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, re.Pattern found
```

Comment: joi, the strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.join` works on *strings*, not `re` objects. Join *then* compile.

```
regex1 = "regex1.*"
regex2 = "regex2\d"
re_dict = {regex1 : "stuff", regex2 : "otherstuff"}
match_multiple = re.compile("|".join(re_dict))
```

note that dicts aren't ordered (unless you're running python 3.6) so if order of the expressions matter, your code may be incorrect

Also note the simplification from `list(re_dict.keys())` to `re_dict` as iterating on a dictionary yields its keys. No need to call `keys` or convert to `list` explicitly.

(well, using a dictionary here is not really useful anyway. How to use the regex as key in the future?)

If you only have access to precompiled expressions, then "emulate" the regex *or* with `any`

```
if any(r.match(string) for r in re_dict):
```

`any` short-circuits, so it exits with `True` as soon as one regex matches.

Or rebuild the pattern by using the `pattern` regex attribute:

```
match_multiple = re.compile("|".join([r.pattern for r in re_dict]))
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not provide the regular expressions and only get them in precompiled form.

Comment: I found out that you can also just use the pattern attribute of the re objects to join.